# The set of real numbers such that $ \lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x)\neq\lim_{x \to a^{-}}f(x) $ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

If $ f :  X \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}  $  is a monotone function  then the set of all points  $ a \in X^{'} $ where ($ X^{'}$  is the set of all accumulation points of $X$) such that is false that $ \lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a^{-}}f(x)   $ is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give two hints.

- Prove that $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = \sup\{f(x) \mid x < a  \}$, and try to guess what $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)$ is. Meaning that lateral limits always exist in the case.
- If $f$ is discontinuous at $p$, then these limits are distinct. Inject the set of discontinuities of $f$ in $\Bbb Q$ by picking a rational in a suitable interval around $f(p)$.